# Setting cross domain cookies by embedding a website?

Tags: facebook, cookies, cross-domain

I recently came across this article, and I was fascinated.

[How Facebook sets and uses cross-domain cookies](http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/)

Anyway, the idea is somewhat like this:

- Facebook is loaded in an iframe on 3rd party websites.
- The cookie is set with Facebook.com as the domain.
- The cookie is read on 3rd party websites, as Facebook is loaded into the iframe.

I tried doing this on my own. I embedded my mysite on another webpage, and set a cookie with the domain set to mysite.com.

However, the cookie was not set, and the process did not work. Am I missing something? Or is the author the article is wrong about the whole concept?

Comment: First of all, there is not really such a thing as a “cross-domain cookie.” The author of that article states, _“Facebook never actually sets cookies cross-domain, they only read cookies cross-domain”_, which is nonsense. The cookie is only send back to the domain it was set from, when a request to that domain is made (which it is, because of the iframe.) That is not “cross-domain”, but simply what is called a 3rd-party cookie.

Comment: How 3rd-party cookies are treated by the browser, depends on the configuration. 3rd-party cookies can be blocked by default, or only be accepted under specific circumstances (f.e. when a p3p policy is presented.)